# Returning strings for numbers if they are primes

Tags: javascript

I was writing a function which checks numbers from 1 to `n` and displays *bip* if the number is even, *bop* if it's a multiple of 5 and *bipBop* if it's both odd and multiple of 5.

What I am trying to do, without success, is to check for primes and concatenate *prime* on the string. i.e.: n(11) Bip, Prime, BipPrime, 4, BipBopPrime, 6, BipPrime, 8, Bip, Bop, BipPrime. But it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
function bipBop(n) {
    
    var numbers = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 2 === 1)
            numbers += 'BipBop, ';
       else if (i % 10 === 0)
            numbers += 'Bop, ';
       else if (i % 2 === 1)
            numbers += 'Bip, ';
        else if (numbers % i === 0)
           numbers += 'Prime, '
       else
            numbers += i + ', ';
    }
    console.log(numbers);
}
```

Comment: Where in your task you see anything about primes? Y

Comment: `numbers` is a string like `'BibBop, '`. What exactly do you expect from `numbers % i`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `else`, the prime block will never execute if the number in question matches any of the preceding conditions (e.g. if it's odd). (Never mind that `numbers % i` isn't a test for primeness, and `numbers` is a string, etc.)